# Highcharts: Add point without connecting series

Tags: javascript, highcharts, series

All,
  I'm trying to allow for a user to click on a highchart between two data points and draw a line.  The resulting line will calculate LARGESTVALUE-SMALLESTVALUE above the rendered line.

I'm attempting to use this example (http://jsfiddle.net/2MdEN/1/).

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'scatter',
                margin: [70, 50, 60, 80],
                events: {
                    click: function(e) {
                        // find the clicked values and the series
                        var x = e.xAxis[0].value,
                            y = e.yAxis[0].value,
                            series = this.series[0];

                        // Add it
                        series.addPoint([x, y]);

                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'User supplied data'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Click the plot area to add a point. Click a point to remove it.'
            },
            xAxis: {
                minPadding: 0.2,
                maxPadding: 0.2,
                maxZoom: 60
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                minPadding: 0.2,
                maxPadding: 0.2,
                maxZoom: 60,
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            'click': function() {
                                if (this.series.data.length > 1) this.remove();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                data: [[20, 20], [80, 80], null, [60, 40], [85, 60]]
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

The problem is that is connects the last data point in the series to the newly added point.  I'd like the points to be detached from the series to allow for lines being drawn above the generated chart.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: I would add a new series, and add the point(s) to that new series instead of to the existing series.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but I'm fighting to get access to "chart" from inside "chart.events.click = function(e){}"

Comment: console.log(this), and see what path leads you to chart :)

Answer (score 1):

You can include a second empty series in your chart config, and change which series you are adding a point to:

```
    events: {
      click: function(e) {
        // find the clicked values and the series
        var x = e.xAxis[0].value,
          y = e.yAxis[0].value,
          series = this.series[1]; <------------

        // Add it
        series.addPoint([x, y]);

      }
    }
```

You can also then move your point click event into the second series, if you don't want users to be able to remove points from the original data:

```
  series: [{
    data: [
      [20, 20],
      [80, 80], null, [60, 40],
      [85, 60]
    ]
  }, {
    id: 'dummy',
    color: 'rgba(204,0,0,0.9)',
    point: {
      events: {
        'click': function() {
          this.remove();
        }
      }
    }
  }]
```

Updated example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/2MdEN/107/

Answer (score 0):

I used the following

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
            margin: [70, 50, 60, 80],
            events: {
                click: function (e) {
                  var c = this.series[0].chart;
                  var s = this.series.length;
                  var x = e.xAxis[0].value;
                  var y = e.yAxis[0].value;

                  if(s == 1) {
                    c.addSeries('newSeries' + new Date());
                    c.series[1].addPoint([x, y]);
                  }else{
                    if(this.series[this.series.length-1].data.length%2 == 1) {
                        c.series[this.series.length-1].addPoint([x, y]);
                    }else{
                        c.addSeries('newSeries' + new Date());
                      c.series[this.series.length-1].addPoint([x, y]);
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'User supplied data!!!!'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the plot area to add a point. Click a point to remove it.'
        },
        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            maxZoom: 60
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            minPadding: 0.2,
            maxPadding: 0.2,
            maxZoom: 60,
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                lineWidth: 1,
                point: {
                    events: {
                        'click': function () {
                            if (this.series.data.length > 1) {
                                this.remove();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [[20, 20], [80, 80]]
        }]
    });
});
```